# Busca por data não funciona

Tags: java, mysql, data

Estou tentanto fazer uma busca no banco de dados mySql fazendo um filtro por data e não está trazendo nenhum resultado. No tela abaixo eu consegui realizar as buscar pelos outros critérios

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código que está fazendo as buscas.

```
public void montaTabelaBusca() {

    String criterio = " WHERE CLIENTE LIKE '" + inpClienteBusca.getText() + "%'"
            + " AND CARRO LIKE '" + inpCarroBusca.getText() + "%'"
            + " AND DESPESA LIKE '" + inpDespesaBusca.getText() + "%'"
            + " AND DATA LIKE '" + inpDataInicialBusca.getText() + "%'";

    ArrayList<Venda> Vendas = VendaDao.getResultadoDaVenda(criterio);
    String[] cabecalhoColunas = {"Id", "Data", "Cliente", "Carro", "Valor","Observação", "Despesa","Valor da despesa"};
    modeloTabela = new DefaultTableModel(cabecalhoColunas, 0);

    for (Venda v : Vendas) {
        String[] novaLinha = {String.valueOf(v.getId()),Formatar("dd/MM/yyyy", v.getData()),String.valueOf(v.getCliente()),String.valueOf(v.getCarro()), Numeros.Formatar("#0.00", v.getValor()),String.valueOf(v.getObservacao()),String.valueOf(v.getDespesa()),Numeros.Formatar("#0.00", v.getValorDespesa())};
        modeloTabela.addRow(novaLinha);
        jtResultadoDaBusca.setModel(modeloTabela);
    }
}
```

//getResultadoDaVenda

```
 public static ArrayList<Venda> getResultadoDaVenda(String condicao) {
    ResultSet resultado = ObjectFactory.getConexao().buscaSql("SELECT * FROM VENDA " + condicao);

    try {
        ArrayList<Venda> listagem = new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultado.next()) {
            Venda vendaPreenchida = preencheVenda(resultado);
            listagem.add(vendaPreenchida);
        }
        return listagem;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("não eoncontrado!");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: O resultado dessa busca é só uma venda? Se não, você não pode aplicar o model dentro do laço, se não não vai resultar nada. Outra coisa, você diz, "não funciona", por favor, quando elaborar uma pergunta, seja mais especifico no problema.

Comment: Sim, o resultado da busca é uma listagem daquela data. Obrigado pela dica !

Comment: Como é esse método `getResultadoDaVenda`? Porque você não passa os parametros dos campos para ele, ao inves da query? Isso ai viola a responsabilidade de cada classe.

Comment: Sim.. estava tentando mas não deu

Comment: Cara, não adicione trecho grande de codigo em comentário, veja como fica, não da pra ler  desse jeito.

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e por o código ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, o teu problema é com o formato da data. O formato padrão que o MySQL usa para salvar data (DATE) é **aaaa-mm-dd**, ou seja, se tu fizer a busca jogando direto na query o que for escrito no campo de busca, ele vai buscar por algo como **"13/04/2017"** sendo que o que está armazenado no banco esta como **"2017-04-13"**. 
Se o que tu quer é fazer somente buscas com data completa, contendo dia, mês e ano, pode usar a função **STR_TO_DATE** do MySQL para transformar a string da busca em DATE na query:

```
"AND DATA = STR_TO_DATE(" + inpDataInicialBusca.getText() + ", '%d/%m/%Y')"
```

Agora, se quiser usar o **LIKE** para buscar por string's de datas incompletas, pode usar a função **DATE_FORMAT** do MySQL para formatar a coluna "DATA" para adequar ao formato que esta usando na query, assim:

```
"AND DATE_FORMAT(DATA, '%d/%m/%Y') LIKE '" + inpDataInicialBusca.getText() + "%'"
```

Comment: Usando o LIKE funcionou.. :D